# Is it possible to get feature importance in CatBoost for a prediction

Tags: python, catboost

I want to know the feature importance for a particular prediction made by the CatBoost model. I know we can get feature importance at the data set level but I want to see if we can do so at each prediction level.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can just create a dataset containing one row (the input you used to obtain that prediction). for example let's name it `single_input_prediction` and feed it to your catboost `get_feature_importance()` function attached to the model you've already trained.

```
model.get_feature_importance(data=single_input_prediction)
```